# Undo prepend on window resize with jQuery

Tags: jquery, resize, width, prepend

I've currently got this jQuery to prepend a `div` if the window is a certain size.

```
if ( $(window).width() < 480) {

   $('nav').css("display","none");

   $('#container').prepend('<div id="nav-btn"></div>');  
}
```

How do I get this to 'continually' check and hide the `<div id="nav-btn"></div>` when the browser is being resized?

EDIT: I want it so that when the window width then reaches 481px the `<nav>` element is set to `display:block;` and the `#nav-btn` is hidden. But dynamically so it all works on resize after resize, not just once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following achieves your requirements (so far as I can tell):

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(window).width() < 482){
       $('nav').css("display","none");
        if (!$('#nav-btn').length){ // makes sure there's only ever one nav-button div
           $('<div />', {'id' : 'nav-btn'})
               .text('This is text, in the nav button')
               .appendTo($('#container'));
        }
    }
    else {
        $('nav').css('display','block');
        $('#nav-btn').remove();
    }
});

$(document).ready(
    function(){
        $(window).trigger('resize'); // making sure the resize stuff happens on DOMReady
    });​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/PhNwT/1/).

References:

- [`appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/).
- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).
- [`trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/).

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    if ($(window).width() >= 481) {
        $("#nav-btn").remove();
        $("nav").css("display", "block");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    // Type your code here
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/resize/

> The resize event is sent to the window element when the size of the browser window changes: